# Is it possible to edit a line already outputted in Windows batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So, I am currently making a "loading screen", and to possibly save some space in my coding, I want to know if you could edit a line already outputted. I would have maybe a bracket [] as one stage of loading, so would it be possible to put one bracket, then wait and see if user presses C (for continue) for 1-2 seconds, and if not go to the next stage ([][])? I currently have a script where [] is set as `load` and for every stage, I do `CLS` and then `echo %LOAD%[]`.

---

In addition, what if I just want to do a status update on a line, such as:

```
Checking status...
Loading server...
```

and then

```
Checking status... OK
Loading server... done
```

---

Bonus points if you can find me a character like `█` that is compatible with Batch.

---

Comment: No but you can use `cls` and a goto loop or the title bar (see `title` command).Check also this discussion: http://ss64.org/viewtopic.php?id=919 .

Comment: @npocmaka: You should delete our comment and make it an answer instead.

Comment: yeah, I know. That is what I am doing currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ommit the *CLS* and recreating the full screen with the help of `set /p`, as `set /p` doesn't output a newline, you can append text.

Normally `set /p` is for assigning text to a variable inputted by a user, but if you use redirection from *NUL* it simply outputs text.

```
@echo off

for /L %%n in (1 1 5 ) do (
  <nul set /p ".=[]"
  ping -n 2 localhost > nul
)
echo(
echo The end
```

The status update you asked for, can be handled the same way, as it only appends something to the line.
If you want to change parts of the line or the complete line, you need to move the cursor back or to the beginning of the line.
Both can be done with the backspace character or the carriage return character.

This is a sample which counts on a fixed screen location

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f %%a in ('copy /Z "%~dpf0" nul') do set "CR=%%a"
for /L %%n in (1 1 1000) do (
  <nul set /p ".=%%n!CR!"
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Creating a blockchar like `█` can be done with

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=1" %%c in (
    `forfiles /p "%~dp0." /m "%~nx0" /c "cmd /c echo 0xde"`) do (
    set BlockChar=%%c
)
echo %BlockChar%
```

Thanks to dbenham [Generate nearly any character, including TAB, from batch](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=20765#p20765)

Comment: You might want to merge this with your other answer to keep it together.